# Why is the following function throwing Object is possibly 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a tiny library with the following structure:

```
library('input').method()
```

This is the code (the `addQuotes` method adds quotes to the `string` input):

```
const library = function (text: string) {
  interface ValueObject {
    addQuotes?: Function
  } // Without this, I get "Property 'to' does not exist on type '{}'."                                                                                                                                                 

  const options: ValueObject = {}

  options.addQuotes = function () {
    if (!text) return ''
    return `"${text}"`
  }

  return options
}

const result = library('test').addQuotes()
console.log(result)
```

Right now, TypeScript is underlying this bit:

```
library('test').addQuotes()
```

Telling me this:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

What could be the problem and how to fix it?

https://jsbin.com/vonawucada/1/edit?js,console

(The code runs here, but in my VS Code setup, I do get the TypeScript error.)

Comment: It is working as expected in the JSbin.

Comment: your `library` is returning `ValueObject` and the interface says that `addQuotes` is optional. So it might or might not be there. So, according to the interface there is no guarantee that the result of `library()` will have an `addQuotes`, therefore TS says that trying to execute `.addQuotes()` can result in an error.

Comment: @decpk Yes, but I get the error in VS Code. I don't know how to make the error appear in JSbin.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the  explanation. How can make the error go away?

Comment: IMO it's a design problem here. If `library` *always* returns something with `addQuotes`, then it's not an optional field. You can amend the type. If it really *could* sometimes be missing, then you need to check if it's there first with `if ("addQuotes" in resultFromLibrary) resultFromLibrary.addQuotes()` for example. Or with optional chaining `library()?.addQuotes()`. Or you can choosse to ignore the error and override the compiler with a non-null assertion `library('test').addQuotes!()` but that's dangerous if `addQuotes` is really missing. I don't know how it should work, so a fix is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your return type of library module. The return type of the library is `ValueObject` which is a private interface. It means its scope is limited to the library module. Typescript will never understand the return type of private interface.

The solution would be to move the `ValueObjet` interface out of the library module scope and make it public so that typescript can understand that what is the return type of the library function.

```
interface ValueObject {
  addQuotes: Function;
}

const library = function (text: string) {
  const options = {} as ValueObject;

  options.addQuotes = function () {
    if (!text) return "";
    return `"${text}"`;
  };

  return options;
};

const result = library("test").addQuotes();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'm curious, why is `as ValueObject` necessary? Isn't the type already assigned on the left side of the `=`? Is it the same as writing `options: ValueObject`?

Comment: `{} as ValueObject` : This means that we are type casting the empty object to our required type. Typescript will throw an error if all the mandatory properties of that type are not defined.

Comment: Is it the same as writing `options: ValueObject`? No, here typescript knows what is the type of options is. But with `{} as ValueObject` , we don't want typescript to know about the type of options so we will typecast to our required type. You may read on [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)

Answer (score 1):

the reason you get `Object is possibly 'undefined'` is because your `addQuotes` property is optional, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties

the solution is one of the following:

1. remove the optional `?` modifier from the property
2. add `!` modifier when accessing the property telling TS that you know that it's assigned (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization):
   `library('test').addQuotes!()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I remove the `?` from `to`, I get: `Property 'to' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'ValueObject'`

Comment: if you remove `?` you'll need to assign the property when the object is created. your code will need to change to `const options: ValueObject = {
addQuotes: function () {
    if (!text) return ''
    return "${text}"
  }}`. but for the 2nd option, there is no shame in using `!` modifier :) as long as you know it's assigned. in my opinion, and according to your code sample, you should remove the `?` sign and assign the property when creating the object because you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are defining addQuotes as an optional function inside the interface using the (?) symbol. Later when you try using it on an object you would need to check if its undefined first before using it.

You can read more here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties